# How to use Azure ML Scoring URI?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm completely new to Azure ML, but I wanted to try out their automated ML UX. So I've followed the instructions to finally deploy my app (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-create-portal-experiments#deploy-your-model). Now I've got my "Scoring URI", but I don't know how to use it? **How can I test an input and get an output - can I do it with Postman?**

- the tutorial doesn't tell me what to do with this "Scoring URI", and so I am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the bottom of the page that you have linked above, there is a link:

[Learn how to consume a web service.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-consume-web-service)

This is exactly on that topic on how to use the deployed web service for scoring (sending an input and getting an output).